# Check occurrences in a list

Tags: python, list

if I want to check if the input is a list of integers with exactly
two occurrences of nineteen and at least three occurrences of five
with one Output, either True or False, I wrote the following code:

```
    nums = [19,19,15,5,3,5,5,2]
def listChecker():
    if nums.count(19) == 2 and nums.count(5) >= 3:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

But when I tried to test the code with

```
listChecker(nums)
```

I get an error message saying: TypeError: listChecker() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

What's wrong? Thank you so much, I am still very new, the learning curve is hard!!
Best

Comment: def listChecker(nums):...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def list_occurrences(l):
    return True if l.count(19) == 2 and l.count(5) >= 3 else False

print(list_occurrences([119, 19, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]))
```

write it this way or in your code change listChecker(nums) to listChecker()

Comment: The `True if condition else False` is unnecessary. Just `return condition` instead.

Answer (score 0):

theoretically we don't need to pass the list name to the function, because `nums` is created in a global scope, so that the function can read the list. but it could be seen as a bad coding practice.

we are going to use this code. the evaluation and returning is done a bit more compact.

```
nums = [19,19,15,5,3,5,5,2]

def listChecker(nums_):
    return nums_.count(19) == 2 and nums_.count(5) >= 3

print(listChecker(nums))
```